# How to filter data from csv files and merge all filtered data?

Tags: python, file, csv, filter

I have the file saved in my folder with all the csv files.
I need a general csv file with all the filtered rows from each small csv files.

Can someone explain to me what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Could you, please attach your code here? Nobody will know what are you doing wrong if nobody knows what are you doing at all

Comment: ````                                                                                                               import pandas as pd
import glob as glob

files= glob.glob('./*.csv')

final_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    df_filtered=df[df['tagIdent'].str.contains("e1_100")]
    pd.concat([final_df, df_filtered] , axis=1)

print (final_df)

df.to_csv('filtered.csv' , sep=",")

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob as glob

files= glob.glob('./*.csv')

final_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    df_filtered=df[df['tagIdent'].str.contains("e1_100")]
    pd.concat([final_df, df_filtered] , axis=1)

print (final_df)

df.to_csv('filtered.csv' , sep=",")
```